# MS Access 2003 and MS VSS ошибка импорта

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Рабочий инструментарий:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
- Visual Source Safe 8.0.50727.42
- MS SQL Server 2012
- Access 2003 11.8166.8172 SP3

Создаю проект ADP на основе уже существующей базы VSS. К базе VSS подключаюсь по VLAN. Импорт всех объектов, кроме форм и отчётов проходит успешно, формы и отчёты в проекте не открываются. При импорте форм и отчётов выпадает окно со следующим сообщением:

> Failed to import file "..." into Microsoft Access.

И так для каждой формы и отчёта. На сайте поддержки есть такое пояснение к этой ошибке:

> This message has the following cause and solution:
>
> The source code control provider could not successfully import a
>   Microsoft Access object.
>   Ensure that the object is not corrupted and that it is consistent with
>   the version in the Visual SourceSafe project.

После закрытия этих окон с сообщением об ошибке импорта, появляется такое же количество других сообщений об ошибке:

> Недостаточно места на диске для временных файлов, необходимых для завершения операции.

Диск почти пуст (150 Гб). Удаление временных файлов не помогает.

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Дело может быть в чем угодно. До тех пор, пока вы задаете подобные вопросы тремя строчками, довольствуйтесь такими ответами.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Поправил описание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта проблема вызвана несовпадением формата файлов по умолчанию в VSS и в Access 2002/2003. Access 2003 создает базы в формате 2000, VSS считает форматом по умолчанию 2002 или 2003. Чинится сменой настроек Access:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927680

To work around this issue, you must change the Default file format setting for Access 2003 and for Access 2002.

1. To do this, follow these steps:
   Check out the Access database from the Visual SourceSafe project, and then open the database in Access .
2. Note the file type for this database. The file type appears in the Access database title bar.
3. On the Tools menu, click Options. The Options dialog box appears.
4. Click the Advanced tab.
5. Under Default file format, click the Access database file type that you noted in step 2 in the Default file format list.
6. Click OK.
7. Close the database, and then check the database in to the Visual SourceSafe project.

<sub>не уверен, стоит ли переводить, скопипастил решение чтобы не было link-only answer</sub>

Comment: Решение, предложенное поддержкой, не очень корректное. Так и не получилось исправить проблему таким образом. Проще оказалось сначала изменить дефолтные настройки, а потом создавать проект.